# "No context-sensitive help installed" , "user32.dll" and "uxtheme.dll" AV errors on Delphi with no reason

Tags: delphi

This is very strange guys. I wrote a simple application. When I make my commands executed fast by moving mouse (event is on mouse move), I experience the following errors if I run my application without debugger (if I do, application just hangs and nothing happens):
1- "No context-sensitive help installed" however i haven't used help in my app.
2- Access violation errors from "uxtheme.dll" and "user32.dll" libraries!

well, i think these errors happen when Windows Messages are sent quickly one after another. I came across these errors a while ago in a huge application. In both application I used SendMessage command, but what am i doing wrong? I'm now using Delphi 2010

Has anyone ever experienced this?!

Edit:
The problem was because of GetForegroundWindow function that I had used in the code of a timer. But I have to use it. What should I do?

Here it is a part of my code: http://www.mediafire.com/?davlsokf8zqq2gs

Comment: You may be having re-entry problems (your event handler is entered again before it has exited from the previous invocation). Try using the asynchronous PostMessage instead of SendMessage.

Comment: @Apalala: I bet this is the solution, i'm gonna test it ;)

Comment: Am I allowed to upload a sample of what I mean here?

Comment: @Javid: you are free to upload as much of your own code as you like.

Comment: Guys! The problem was because of GetForegroundWindow function that I had used in the code of a timer. (As you know GetForegroundWindow is called from user32.dll) But I have to use it. What should I do?

Comment: @javid we can't answer this because we can't guess how these fragments of your code interact and what the intended purpose is

Comment: @david: alright. I'll make a sample as soon as i get some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. My bad!
ApProgressBar was calling Paint while Tmessage was invalid!
Thanks to all people who cared about the question.

Comment: can you detail this?

Comment: @Allforfree: You can't call Paint with just any `TMessage`. The message data must be initialized properly first. Are you having the same problem?

Comment: @Javid could you please give some more details? I have the same problem "No context-sensitive help installed." while I dont use any help at all

Answer (score 2):

From the first glance it looks like some memory corruption OR incorrect memory access. Maybe you are sending PChars with your messages, and when migrating to Delphi 2010 you have not properly and completely updated your code. So the first thing to do is inspect all places where you use(d) PChar, PAnsiChar and PWideChar.

Comment: Well, I know all about PWideChar and other stuff; I actually executed a similar code in D7 and no error occured.

Comment: @Javid: The fact that the code worked in D7 but doesn't work in D2010 **supports** the hypothesis that the problem is related to the migration AnsiString -> UnicodeString that took place in Delphi 2009.